# An alldifferent for tuples

Tags: prolog, sudoku, clpfd, eclipse-clp

I'm trying to solve a sudoku with the viewpoint that every number has 9 positions. This is the representation for my sudoku:

[image: sudoku]

From the table you can read that number **5** has following positions (Row,Col) in the sudoku: (2,8),(4,2),(6,5).

When I mention a **row** in my explanation, I mean a row like this:
[image: row]

For example, the above **row**  is row **1**.

What I have done is the following:

- For every row check if all ROW-Values in that row are different using `alldifferent` from `ic_global`.
- Do the same as above but then for the COLUMN-Values.
- For every row, check if the square numbers are different (calculated using a row and col value each time), using `alldifferent` again.

The above things work fine and I get a solution for the sudoku but not the correct one. This is because I have to check one more thing: **every position must be different**. With the current state of my solver I could get a solution that has multiple numbers on the same position, f.e.: **2** and **3** could both be at position **(5,7)** because I don't check if all positions are different.

How would I tackle this problem?
I tried to get ALL the positions in one list in tuple form and then check if all tuples are different but I have been struggling for hours and I'm getting really desperate. I hope I can find a solution here.

**EDIT: Added code**

[image: code]

Comment: How do you check for the blocks with x-y coordinates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you already know, `all_different/1` and related constraints work on **integers**. Also, in your case, you are actually interested in a special case of tuples, namely **pairs** consisting of rows and columns.

So, your question can actually be reduced to:

> How can I injectively **map** pairs of integers to integers?

Suppose you have pairs of the form `A-B`, where both `A` and `B` are constrained to `1..9`.

I can put such pairs in a *one-to-one correspondence* to integers in several ways. A very easy function that does this is: **9×A + B**. Think about it!

Thus, I recommend you map such positions to integers in this way or a similar one, and then post `all_different/1` on these integers.

**Exercise**: Think about other possible mappings and their properites. Then generalize them to work on *tuples*.

Comment: Thank you mat, I'll try that. I thought of the idea of mapping them but didn't think of that function and wasn't sure if it was the best way to solve my problem, I tried Row x Col x SquareNumber but that didn't work out. I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: Your mapping probably was not injective.